# Masonry layout adaptative to child's height

Tags: css, vue.js

I have a page on my website in which I display some cards in a masonry layout.

It's implemented in Vue 3 and I want the layout do adapt to the container's child heights.

The layout flows from top to bottom, left to right. Just like the images shows:

[image]

To achieve this, I divided the cards in different columns using the `order` CSS property together with a flexbox.

However, for this to work, the parent container needs to have a fixed height.

I want this to be the minimum height possible to make sure all cards fit, that is, the exact height of the longest column of the layout.

I tried to set the container's height to 0 initially and then update it based on the card's height, however, this doesn't work very well and is really janky.

```
<template>
    <section class="container" :style="{ height: containerHeight }">
        <project-card v-for="i in projects.length" :key="i" :project="projects[i - 1]"
                      :style="{ order: (i - 1) % numberColumns + 1, width: (100 / numberColumns) - 1.5 + '%' }"
                      :ref="setProjectCardRef">
        </project-card>

        <span v-for="i in numberColumns - 1" :key="i" :style="{ order: i }" class="item break"></span>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
import Projects from "@/api/Projects";
import ProjectCard from "@/components/ProjectCard";

export default {
    name: "Projects",
    components: {
        "project-card": ProjectCard,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            projects: [],
            projectCardsRefs: [],
            windowWidth: window.innerWidth,
            containerHeight: "100%"
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getData();
        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth
        })
    },
    methods: {
        getData() {
            Projects.list().then((response) => {
                for (let project of response.data)
                    project.image_url = process.env.VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT + project.image_url;
                this.projects = response.data;
            });
        },
        setProjectCardRef(el) {
            if (!this.projectCardsRefs.includes(el))
                this.projectCardsRefs.push(el)
        }
    },
    computed: {
        numberColumns() {
            return Math.round(this.windowWidth / 400)
        },
    },
    async updated() {
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 200));
        let heights = Array(this.numberColumns).fill(0)
        
        for (let i = 0; i < this.projectCardsRefs.length; i++) {
            const style = this.projectCardsRefs[i].$el.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(this.projectCardsRefs[i].$el);
            const marginTop = parseInt(style.marginTop.match(/\d+/g)[0]);
            const height = parseFloat(style.height.match(/\d+(.\d+)?/g)[0]);
            heights[i % this.numberColumns] += height + marginTop
        }

        this.containerHeight = 40 + Math.max(...heights) + "px";
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.container {
    @apply flex flex-col flex-wrap space-y-6;
}
.break {
    @apply mx-3 w-0;
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
</style>
```

How can I set the container's height based on its children in a more responsive way?

Comment: Define "more responsive" and no, flexbox requires a defined height. You really need masonry.js I would suggest.

Comment: You can see how it's currently implemented [here](https://educorreia932.dev/projects).
There's a brief moment in the beginning, while it's still updating the container and the contents are loading, in which the cards jump around.
This happens when the page is resized as well, and not always does it calculate the height correctly, sometimes being some pixels away from the necessary height and making the content be out of place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Paulie_D's suggestion, I implemented it using Masonry.JS

```
<template>   
    <section id="container" v-masonry transition-duration="0.2s" item-selector=".item"
             percent-position="true" ref="container" :gutter="spaceBetween">
        <project-card class="item" v-masonry-tile v-for="i in projects.length" :key="i" :project="projects[i - 1]"
                      :style="`width: ${itemWidth}px; margin-bottom: ${spaceBetween}px`"/>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
import Projects from "@/api/Projects";
import ProjectCard from "@/components/ProjectCard";

export default {
    name: "Projects",
    components: {
        "project-card": ProjectCard,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            projects: [],
            containerWidth: 0,
            spaceBetween: 20
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getData();

        new ResizeObserver(this.onResize).observe(document.getElementById("container"))
        this.onResize()
    },
    methods: {
        getData() {
            Projects.list().then((response) => {
                for (let project of response.data)
                    project.image_url = process.env.VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT + project.image_url;

                this.projects = response.data;
            });
        },
        onResize() {
            this.containerWidth = document.querySelector("main").offsetWidth;
        }
    },
    computed: {
        numberColumns() {
            return Math.round(this.containerWidth / 400);
        },
        itemWidth() {
            return (this.containerWidth - this.numberColumns * this.spaceBetween) / this.numberColumns;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```